# Steps for representation of spatial boundaries, dividing into grids of equal size, assigning entities to grids

Tags: python, google-maps, gis, geopy

I have some data related to phenomenon between 2 geolocated(lat/lon) entities for a certain country. My high level algorithm is like this:

1. Get a boundary of country(shp/geojson). I have this.
2. Divide country area into 20km x20km grid (haversine etc). Not sure exactly how to do this.
3. Store this information into some data structure not a plot for visualisation.
4. Once I have the grid data structure, assign my geolocated entities into pair of grids. Correlated entities are pairwise (X1,X2). Depending on where the w entities are located, I will want to store this Information into a data structure. Like : (X1,X2): grid20,grid55. Now I have a mapping of all my geolocated entities with grids they fall into.
5. Once I have this data structure in place, I have to randomly assign(permutation) each entity to a random grid. This is part of a permutation test to see if entities have a certain geographical function or just by chance.

I understand the high level of what I need to do but not how to do it practically. I saw some posts about dividing earth into grids. But seemed more like for plotting rather than usage as a data structure. any help in how I can do this is appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend the package xarray to store the information in a datastructure. Randomizing permutations should be possible with standard python libraries or numpy.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I would need some guidance with each of the algorithm steps.

Comment: Also take a look at geohashing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash - which is essentially what you are implementing.  Looks like python has a library for it: https://pypi.org/project/python-geohash/